# In a Tic Tac Toe game board find probability table

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got stuck with one probability calculation for this question, would appreciate your help finding the mistake.

the question: "given tic tac toe game board $3\times 3$. in each cell we write either X or O (randomly).

Let there be:

- X - Num of Xs in the first row
- Y - Num of columns that have 3 Xs in them.

find the (X,Y) probability table."

This is what I did and I got stuck with calculating $P(X=1,Y=0)$. from some reason I get answer that is greater then 1...

[image]

Comment: I suspect $\Pr(Y = 0 \mid X=1) = \frac34$ and $\Pr(X=1)= {3\choose 1}\frac1{2^3} = \frac38$ so  $\Pr(X=1, Y = 0) = \frac{9}{32}=0.28125$

Comment: I also suspect $\Pr(Y = 0 \mid X=3) = \left(\frac34 \right)^3$ and $\Pr(X=3)= {3\choose 3}\frac1{2^3} = \frac18$ so  $\Pr(X=3, Y = 0) = \frac{27}{512}=0.052734375$

Comment: @Henry how do you know $P(Y=0|X=1)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $P(Y=0|X=3)=(\frac{3}{4})^3$? how did you reach these values?

Comment: If there is one X in the top row, you want the two below it to not both be X.  If there are three Xs in the top row you want the two below each to not both be X.

Comment: @Henry got you! thanks! isn't there an option to directly find out $P(X=3,Y=0)$? without finding out $P(Y=0|X=3)$ before?

Comment: You can compute $P(X=3,Y=0)$ because in each column you need an $X$ in the top, probability $1/2$ and at least one $O$ below, probability $3/4$, so the chance in each column is $3/8$ and you cube that to get $27/512$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have $X=1,Y=0$ we can choose the column with $X$ in the top row in $3$ ways.  That column needs an $X$ in the top and at least one $O$ below, probability $3/8$.  The other two columns need $O$ on top, so the total is $3 \cdot \frac 38 \cdot (\frac 12)^2=\frac 9{32}$